# how to find the particular date data or next date data in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the particular date data from database,
my concept is if `2018-11-30` is given to find in database if the date is present in database it should display the date in output, if not present it should add +1 date to `2018-11-30` and try to find the next date `2018-12-01` like wise it goes on.

but i am facing the problem the date is not checked in the database.i am not sure weather my code is correct or wrong can any one give me solution for it.

this is my code

```
$Firstdate = '2018-11-29';
$Lastdate = '2018-12-03'; 

$Sql2 = "SELECT ScheduleDate FROM `empdet`";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $Sql2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    if($row["ScheduleDate"]==$Firstdate)
    {
        $DBfirstdate==$Firstdate; 
        echo "$DBfirstdatebb",$DBfirstdate;
        break;
    }
    else {
        $checkFDBdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($Firstdate)));

        if($row["ScheduleDate"]==$checkFDBdate)
        {
            $DBfirstdate=$checkFDBdate;
            echo "$DBfirstdate",$DBfirstdate;
            break;
        }
    }
}


$Sql3 = "SELECT ScheduleDate FROM `empdet`";
$result3 = mysqli_query($con, $Sql3);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
    if($row["ScheduleDate"] == $Lastdate) {
        $DBlastdate==$Lastdate;   
        echo "$DBlastdateBB",$DBlastdate;
        break;
    }
    else {
        $checkLDBdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($Lastdate)));

        if($row["ScheduleDate"]==$checkLDBdate)
        {
            $DBlastdate=$checkLDBdate;
            echo "$DBlastdate",$DBlastdate;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$sql ="select * from empdet where ScheduleDate between '".$DBfirstdate."' and '".$DBlastdate."'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
```

Comment: [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) has WHERE clauses to select data. PHP has functions to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: i cannot understand bro @dankblack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ScheduleDate FROM `empdet` where ScheduleDate > '$Firstdate' and ScheduleDate < '$Lastdate' order by ScheduleDate limit 1
```

Try this way. You will get the first raw from the date range given.

Comment: i cannot execute his statement because i have to find weather the $Firstdate and $Lastdate is present in table or not so only i am trying above concept.but cannot able to do it.

Comment: Give a specific range whatever you want. So u'll get the first result as the latest available date

Comment: it worked i did slight changes $Sqlq12 = "SELECT ScheduleDate FROM `empdet` where ScheduleDate <= '$Lastdate'  ORDER BY ScheduleDate DESC  limit 1";

Comment: @selvasurya That's great, but that's not what you said you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select stuff from somewhere where something > 'value' order by something limit 1
```

Comment: It would be nice if there was some text explaining your answer, not everybody read code and just understands.